# Problem using dict and zip with special characters

Tags: python

In this program zip() seems to be altering special characters, how can I fix it to print € twice?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

d = dict(zip("a", "€"))
print(d["a"])
print("€")
```

Output

```
�
€
```

Desired output

```
€
€
```

Thanks!
Edit: Python 2.7.12

Comment: In my case(macbook pro) works fine.

Comment: Specify which Python version are you using. On Python 3.7 runs fine.

Comment: It should work fine. Works fine for windows as well.

Comment: Your edit says that you’re using Python 2, yet the `print()` in your code indicate that you’re using Python 3. I’m voting to close this, it’s unclear, and it appears that other people can’t reproduce the issue.

Comment: @AMC print() does not indicate use of Python 3. Parentheses can be used in Python 2.

Comment: @vuoriov4 Indeed, someone else had pointed it out, although they seem to have deleted their comments. Can you confirm that you were using `from __future__ import print_function`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably running Python 2.7 that does not use unicode by default.

In that case use

```
d = dict(zip("a", u"€"))
```

Edit: Python 2.7 uses ascii for strings unless otherwise specified.
Ascii code is an 8 bit code and it does not include the € sign.
In contrast, your text editor probably uses UTF-8 or UTF-16 which does include the € sign. This means when you enter:

```
print("€")
```

You see the € sign because your text editor supports it, but the python interpreter sees an ascii string that does not have the € sign. So by switching to python 3 the problem is resolved because python 3 uses unicode for strings by default, the interpreter sees a unicode string. In python 2.7 unicode is used by preceding the string with an "u". Then the interpreter sees a unicode string and knows the € sign.

Comment: @vuoriov4 Yes in python 3 unicode is the default string representation, but in python 2.7 it is ascii.